# ASP.NET response.redirect with IIS7

Tags: asp.net, ajax, response.redirect

I have a site that is up and running on IIS6 in Windows 2003, and a development environment in XP. Everything works just fine.

I have been forced to create a new development environment in Windows 7.

Since using this, I have found that Reponse.Redirect no longer works... in some situations!

I have the following code:

`Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL( PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID ));`

It works fine on IIS6.

It also works fine in most of the site on IIS7.5. However in some pages, it's not.

I have looked at the returning header, and can see there is a GET response in the Request header, which is for the correct page it should redirect too, but it's not!

There is an RadAjaxPanel around the buttons used to fire this redirect, but in a parent control. The buttons not working are in a separate ascx control.

I have the following in my Web.Config that I've found from other similar posts:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

And

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,  System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

(both have ending tags)

But this hasn't helped.

Can anyone think of anything to try to get these working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL( PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID ), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution but a workaround -

```
private void Redirect(string url)
{
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csName = "RedirectScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
      StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
      csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> ");
      csText.Append("window.location.href = {0} </", url);
      csText.Append("script>");
      cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
    }
}
```

Call from a page -

```
Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL( PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID ));
```

This will use JavaScript to let your page redirect.
You can move above method in a common utility class.